# VB.NET drag frop files from form to folder?

Tags: vb.net, listview, drag-and-drop

I am making a file container that adds and extracts files. It allows adding files to the archive by dragging and dropping them into a listview, but now I want to support the other way around, draging multiple items from the listview and into a local folder on the computer, and have the destination folder returned to me so I can process it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start handling `MouseDown` event and creating a list of selected items:

```
Private Sub myListBox_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles myListBox.MouseDown
    Dim selectedItemsList As New Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    selectedItemsList.Add(myListBox.SelectedItem.ToString)
    Dim dataObj As New DataObject
    dataObj.SetFileDropList(selectedItemsList)
    myListBox.DoDragDrop(dataObj, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub
```